# Problem plotting from data

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot some data like this with pgfplots:

```
      t                      s

      0                      1.00000000000000e(-5)
     4.61757198763792e(-16)  1.00000000647317e(-5)
     9.23514397527583e(-16)  1.00000001356562e(-5)
     3.23230039134654e(-15)  1.00000005831684e(-5)
     5.54108638516550e(-15)  1.00000011854923e(-5)
     1.70850163542603e(-14)  1.00000065190426e(-5)
     2.86289463233551e(-14)  1.00000157217943e(-5)
     8.63485961688291e(-14)  1.00001197341306e(-5)
     1.44068246014303e(-13)  1.00003202774067e(-5)
     4.32666495241673e(-13)  1.00027597798202e(-5)
     7.21264744469043e(-13)  1.00075385248608e(-5)
     1.21257733711233e(-12)  1.00205586934983e(-5)
     1.70388992975561e(-12)  1.00379556373569e(-5)
```

The name of the .dat file is data.dat. The code is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=Q Series,
ylabel=P Values]
\addplot [color=black,y=s, x=t] table {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
 Missing number, treated as zero. ...[color=black,y=s, x=t] table {data.dat};
```

If I change 'e' for '*10^', I get this:

```
 Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '1.00000000000000*10^(-5)' as a  floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '*10^(-5)'.. ...[color=black,y=s, x=t] table {data.dat};
```

Anybody knows what I'm not doing well?

Comment: If you remove the `(` and `)` from the data file, everything works as expected (the number format should be `4.61757198763792e-16`)

Comment: I had tried everything instead of that. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the data file was ill-formatted, see comments.